# How to send/transfer data from a java desktop/swing app to a java web app

Tags: java, swing, web

I am developing a Java swing/desktop application and I want to send data from the desktop app to a Java web app running on tomcat, I have searched for this kind of question here as I expected to see something similar but I couldn't find it. Please a need suggestions on what kind of technology to use.

Comment: Via HTTP POST request.

Comment: If you are using a database, both applications can simply share the same database or the needed tables.

Comment: I didn't downvote but please research before posting such questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make use of an HTTP library such as [Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html)  The api of indiviual libraries vary a little bit, but in general they provide you all the tools you need to set up an HTTP POST, GET, etc with complete control over headers, content, query, etc and most (including HTTPClient) have support for complex authentication methods and support HTTPS connections.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the OP's needs pure Java may well be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Spring RESTClient.
See this : http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/contact-rest-services-client.html